# Javascript post request one key and multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have a script to submit an array of id's to be deleted.  The script is not tied to a form.

The data is in the form of `{'id': [1,2]}`.

When I run the script, the form data is changed to id[]: 1

I have tried `$.param()`, but that just creates a single string.

I could join 1,2 into a string (i.e. `{id: "1,2"}`, but would prefer to avoid that.  Any suggestions?

```
function delete_messages(event){
   let data = {id: [1,2]};
   event.preventDefault();
   let parameters = {
     url: '/message/delete'
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     dataType: "html"
   };
   addcsrf();
   $.ajax(parameters).done(function(data){
      alert("successfully deleted");
   })
   .fail(function(data){
      alert("failed to delete");
   });
 }
```

Flask Code

```
@bp.route('/message/delete', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def message_delete():
    message_ids = request.form.get('msg_id')
    deleted = []
    for id in message_ids:
        msg = RecipientData.query.get(id)
        if msg is not None and msg.user_id == current_user.id:
            msg.update(status='trash')
    return redirect(url_for('main.view_messages', folder="inbox"))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem a bit? Can't understand the question

Comment: your data seems to be creating a json object with a value named 'id' with is the array, but your server side code wants a field that's an array and its named msg_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids=[];
ids[0] = 1;
ids[1] = 2;
```

In the ajax request, change the data as given below:

```
 data: {ids:ids},
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the 2nd line of code.  data should have been {id: [1,2]}, which looks equivalent to what you have listed above.  Then when i look at the form data the browser is submitting, its changed to id[] : 1